# How can I create Starcraft 2 maps with snow?

Tags: starcraft-2

I saw some replays on snow maps. How can I create a custom map with this snow/mountain setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you would have to import a custom tileset, created by the community, but apparently there already is a snow tile set in the game. (just hidden) This [link](http://www.sc2mapster.com/forums/resources/tutorials/17499-video-snow-tileset-tutorial/#p7) explains how you use that tile set and add snowy weather.

Comment: The link is broken now. Is there a working link? Better yet, could the actual procedure be added to this answer (or as a new answer), to prevent this problem from happening again in the future? :-)